# Key mapping sony vaio

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

I have Sony Vaio laptop. My left arrow key is not working. The same key is used for <kbd>Home</kbd> with <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I want to map it to the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, which is the key next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Keyboard 5000 utility can do this even if you don't own the keyboard / mouse combo the software is still free to all using windows.

I've heard good things but never tried keytweak myself

http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

I use [KeyTweak](http://www.tucows.com/preview/327616/KeyTweak)

The good thing about this is that you can hold the key you want to map down OR select from a list. It can' remap shortcuts unfortunately.

As your left arrow isn't working, you probably won't be able to hold the key down, but you can select it from the keyboard (shown below:)

[image]